# Android Studio - CheckBox is making App crash

Tags: android, checkbox, crash

I am currently working on an activity for a register page where you input your info and it would store it in an object.

This problem arose when I tried to implement Check boxes into my code.

Is there a solution for this?

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button bRegister, bBack;
    EditText etName, etAge, etUsername, etPassword;
    CheckBox cbAccount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        // Get user info
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassowrd);
        bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
        bBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBack);
        cbAccount = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbAccount);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        bBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbAccount.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    boolean account = false;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
        //"switch" is like an if statement, but one can put multiple "cases"
        switch(view.getId()) { 
            // When user registers, store info
            case R.id.bRegister:
                // Store user info
                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
                boolean accountSend = account;
                // Call method to store user info to Login.java class for authentication
                userLocalStorage uls = userLocalStorage.getInstance();

                uls.setUsername(username);
                uls.setPassword(password);
                uls.setName(name);
                uls.setAge(age);
                uls.setAccount(accountSend);

                startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));

                break;
            case R.id.bBack:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
                break;
            case R.id.cbAccount:
                if (checked) {
                    account = true;
                } else {
                    account = false;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the logcat**
01-24 20:43:15.971 8074-8074/com.example.huynh.nom E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.huynh.nom, PID: 8074
                                                                     java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
                                                                         at com.example.huynh.nom.Register.onClick(Register.java:44)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Where is the error log from logcat?

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to this.  I have been setting breakpoints and using the debugger but I failed to find the error.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? If so there is a menu at the bottom called "Android Monitor" that has a tab called logcat where the crash stack trace will be printed. If you post that here it typically helps quite a bit in finding the problem.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you! The logcat is up.

Comment: Change this line ``boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();`` to ``boolean checked = cbAccount.isChecked();``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onClick` handler you have the following line:

```
boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
```

Since you registered the same handler to be used by multiple different views that will not work since they are not all CheckBoxes.

Remove that line and you can do this instead:

```
case R.id.cbAccount:
    if (cbAccount.isChecked()) {
        account = true;
    } else {
        account = false;
    }
break;
```

Comment: It's up and running again!  
I'll keep this in mind when programming in the future! 
Many thanks George!

Comment: You're welcome. If this fixed your problem can you please accept the answer by clicking the check mark?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
```

This is called whenever `bRegister`, `bBack`, or `cbAccount` are clicked, because you are setting the click listeners here:

```
    bRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    bBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    cbAccount.setOnClickListener(this);
```

However, only one of these is actually a `CheckBox`, so when either of the other two are clicked, it causes a bad cast.

Therefore, move the `boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();` to within your `case R.id.cbAccount:`.

Comment: What is the best solution for preventing this bad cast?

Comment: Move the cast to within your `case R.id.cbAccount`. At this point, you know that what you are casting is actually a `CheckBox` and not some other view like a `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

I see something wrong with this: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBo`x, can you check in your layout file and make sure you use correct widget.